# jQuery load url issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

We have suddenly an issue with jQuery load function.

Let's say we have an url of the view/page which is "www.domain.com/register" and inside that view we have scripts such as `$('#div').load('messages/pixeltracker.htm');`
before, it it always returns **www.domain.com/messages/pixeltracker.htm** it always ups one folder.

but now, it's returning a wrong url **www.domain.com/register/messages/pixeltracker.htm** which obviously will return 404 error and upon debugging i've notice that I need to add ../ before messages/pixeltracker.htm something like
`$('#div').load('../messages/pixeltracker.htm');`

I'm just wondering if it's a server or a browser issue?

I hope someone could explain it.

Regards

Comment: that is because you were using relative path man. http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html if you use absolute path,  you wont have this issue

Comment: but it was working before, it's automatically one up folder even though were not using ../ i can't understand. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you hitting the page as www.domain.com/register/ before? If you always used the backslash at the end, the messages/pixeltracker.htm would work. Otherwise, it should not be correct.

Comment: I've just tried it and still didn't work. Thanks for answering though.